# Can a friend go to the passport agency and renew my passport for me?

Tags: usa, passports

My flight is in 1 week and my passport has expired. I have all of my completed docs/materials but I'm not able to go to the regional passport agency myself. Is it possible for my friend to go to the agency in my place if I sign an authorization form?

Edit: I know third party expedited service agencies are allowed to renew on my behalf as long as I fill out an authorization form, but their fees are exorbitant. I'm just wondering if the same permissions could be applied to a third party individual (instead of agency). I wasn't able to find anything online that specifically answered that question

Comment: Which form are you using? DS-82 (i.e. you eligible to apply by mail) or DS-80 (which requires personal appearance)? Also, I suggest you call the appointment hotline (there are humans there), and ask.

Comment: @GeorgeY.: Renewing by mail with DS-82 would have basically zero chance of being completed in a week.

Comment: Even with expedited service at a passport agency, they quote 8 days processing time.  You may need to bite the bullet and pay the fees to change your flight dates.

Comment: @Tom If you show up with airline tickets in hand, they can usually get it done much sooner, often even the same day, but they don't guarantee it.

Comment: @GeorgeY.: Incidentally, Form DS-80 [doesn't seem to exist](http://www.state.gov/m/a/dir/forms/passport/).  Are you thinking of DS-11?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: yes, you're indeed correct.

Comment: @ZachLipton - "don't guarantee it" plus the OP will not be present, hence my advice about considering changing date is still valid.

Comment: @GeorgeY. I'm applying with a DS-82. If I did not have the severe time crunch I could renew by mail. I called the appointment hotline but will try calling on Monday to see if I can reach an actual person.

Answer (score 3):

You have to go in person. However, you can hire a courier to act on your behalf. The State Department website implies they have no special relationship or permission, but they do - a courier has to be registered with the US State Department.

This [article](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/advice/2013/05/14/passport-visa-services-are-often-worth-the-extra-money/2159409/) has a very good explanation.

Given your time frame, it sounds like your best bet is to hire a registered courier.

Comment: Thanks, I might have to resort to playing hooky from work to stand in line at the agency since I can't get any time off.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you cannot.  Every reference I could find to applying at a passport agency uses the phrase "in person" and says nothing about sending a friend or other agent.  Also, it says [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/applyinperson.html) that you have to show identification at the passport agency, so your friend can't go and pretend that she is you.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that information for if I needed a first time passport, but for renewing passports you don't necessarily have to go in person. I know couriers are allowed to go on my behalf to renew my passport, so I'm just wondering if that applies to a person as well assuming I sign an authorization form.